# Too many records in mySQL recordset, wrong join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Table 1 ( id, name, description )
Table 2 ( id, table1id, type, value)
```

And now I want to select all records in "table 1" to show if they have a value in "table 2". This works, however if "table 2" contains multiple records for "type = color" and with the same "table1.id" I only want to see 1 record returned. Now I get multiple records returned.

This is my SQL command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.*, t2.value
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.table1id = table1.id AND t2.type = 'color';
```

Could someone point me out what I am doing wrong, I cannot seem to grasp it...

Comment: This is how joins work and the `distinct` won't change anything. It operates on *all* columns of the select statement, so it will only remove rows if you have multiple values for `t2.value` (those obfuscated column names don't really help...)

Comment: "I only want to see 1 record returned..." wich one do you want?

Comment: I want the first record returned (it does not matter much which one from the second table is returned). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` instead of `distinct`:

```
SELECT t1.*, group_concat(t2.value) as t2values
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.table1id = t1.id AND t2.type = 'color'
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

If you want only one value, you can use `min()`, or `max()` instead of `group_concat()`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `max()` or `min()` instead of `group_concat()`because the OP only wants one value?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . The OP says "one record", not "one value".  I just made the assumption that s/he would want to see all the associated values.  But maybe I misunderstood that.

Comment: @Gordon, you have written t1.* in select , but you group by has only one column!

Comment: @AK47: To group by id and show all the other columns non-aggregated is totally fine in MySQL; it's an enhancement to the SQL standard.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . This use of the `group by` is actually quite consistent with the standard, assuming that `id` is declared as unique (or a primary key) in `table1`.  MySQL also supports this syntax in other circumstances, which violates (or "extends" if you prefer) the standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only `value` from table2, You can use a co-related subquery

```
SELECT  t1.*,
(SELECT value FROM table2 WHERE table1id = t1.id AND `type` = 'color' LIMIT 1) `value`
FROM table1 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to see table1 records, so select table1 records. Don't join. To see if there exists a value in table2, you can use a count select to see how many matches you get:

```
SELECT table1.*, (select count(*) from table2 t2 WHERE t2.table1id = t1.id AND t2.type = 'color')
FROM table1 t1;
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear, but I want 1 record from t2, including a value from t2 in the recordset. So not a combined set of records including multiple t2 records. Only 1 is enough..

Therefore I think your solution does not work in the way I meant it.

Comment: Well, if you want a random value from t2 then just use min or max instead of count. If you want a string listing all values then use group_count.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT t1.*, t.value FROM table1 as t1
 outer apply
    (
    select top 1 * from table2 t2
    where t1.id=t2.id and t2.type = 'color'
    order by id desc
)as t
```

Comment: That's not valid for MySQL

Comment: Yes friend, code which I have given is of SQL Server, I don't have used MySql, so you can pick up logic from this ans, not syntax. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Well MySQL neither has lateral joins (named `outer apply` in SQL Server) nor does it have `top` (and besides a lateral join isn't necessary here anyway)